# Finding the probability that a number drawn is highest in rounds of games

Tags: probability

In a game, 6 balls are chosen from a set of 40 balls numbered from 1 to 40. Find the probability that the number 30 is drawn and it is the highest number drawn in at least one of the next five games.

I have $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(5,6/29)$ and $P(X=1\mid X\text{ is max}) = \frac{P(X=1\text{ and }X\text{ is max})}{P(X\text{ is max})}=\frac{\binom{5}{1}(1/40)(23/29)^4}{6/29}$ which is obviously incorrect.

Why is this wrong?

UPDATE:

Parts a) and B) asked for

a) In a game, 6 balls are chosen from a set of 40 balls numbered from 1 to 40. Find the probability that the number 30 is drawn in exactly two of the next five games.

b) In a game, 6 balls are chosen from a set of 40 balls numbered from 1 to 40. Find the probability that the number 30 is drawn in at least two of the next five games.

Which I was able to successfully solve with

$X\sim Bin(5,6/40)$

Thus for the main question
in my post, I was led to believe to use the binomila distribution. Do you think that this could be a method for part c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, a simpler approach is to see that the probability of choosing number $30$ in a game and it being the highest number is,

$ \displaystyle p = {29 \choose 5} / {40 \choose 6} = \frac{87}{2812}$

So, we have $X\sim Bin\left(5, \frac{87}{2812}\right)$ and we need to find $P(X \geq 1)$ which can simply be written as,

$ \displaystyle \small P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{87}{2812}\right)^5$

Comment: In the calculator, this gives 0.14541 which is the closest yet to my answers which say 0.14 (2dp). However, I trust you and I think you are probably right.

Comment: What an interesting approach. I was thinking something along the lines of a binomial distribution. Do you think there is any binomial distribution related method? Please see my updated post

Comment: You are absolutely correct and what you say is in fact simpler. I just edited my answer to show that.

Comment: HI, this gives exactly the correct answer! Thank you so much for the help, I've been stuck on this for days. However, it is actually slightly different to your original answer. What was wrong with your initial attempt which got 0.145 instead of 0.141?

Comment: oh I actually did not calculate either of them so did not notice that answers were different. Let me check where I went wrong earlier.

Comment: Now I did the calculation and my previous answer and this answer both match and the answer should be $0.14541$. The problem is a typo in the last step of my answer where I typed in $87 / 2912$ by mistake, instead of $87 / 2812$. I have not corrected yet. Once you see it, I will correct the typo.

Comment: I see. Yes, you are definitely correct. I think my solutions have incorrectly rounded down instead of up.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- For a particular game, you want the probability that $30$ is drawn and the other five numbers drawn are smaller.

  - one way is to look at the probability all six are $30$ or less, and the probability all six are $29$ or less
- You then want the probability this is not what happens in a particular game
- and then the probability it does not happen in $5$ games in a row
- and finally the probability that it does happen at least once in five games

Comment: I attempted the question using your hints and have posted the attempt as an answer but it is getting me nowhere

Comment: @user71207 my suggestions lead to $1-\left(1 - \left(\dfrac{30 \choose 6}{40 \choose 6}-\dfrac{29 \choose 6}{40 \choose 6}\right)\right)^5$ $=\frac{25567117050049707}{175823362645752832} \approx 0.1454137$

Answer (score 0):

> For a particular game, you want the probability that 30 is drawn and the other five numbers drawn are smaller.
> one way is to look at the probability all six are 30 or less, and the probability all six are 29 or less

That means $P(X≥1 \text{and others are smaller}) = 1 - P(X≥1 \text{and others are smaller})=1-\binom{29}{6}(\frac{1}{29})^5$

OR $P(X=0 \text{and others are smaller}) = \binom{29}{6}(\frac{1}{29})^5$.

Then adding them together gives 1, which is wrong